How do I get a list of active app windows with Swift in MacOS?
I'm trying to get a list of active windows for the app that a user is currently using. My ultimate goal is to be able to resize them to a certain height/width on some button combination presses. My app is a MenuBar App. Here is my code:
import Cocoa
import ApplicationServices

struct WindowManager {
    func handleWindowResizeOperation() {
        self.getFocusedApp()
    }
    
    private func getFocusedApp() {
        let options: NSDictionary = [kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt.takeRetainedValue() as NSString: true]
        let accessEnabled = AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions(options)
        
        guard accessEnabled else {
            print("Accessibility permissions are not enabled.")
            return
        }
        
        guard let app = NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication else {
            print("No frontmost application found.")
            return
        }
        
        let appElement = AXUIElementCreateApplication(app.processIdentifier)
        
        var value: CFTypeRef?
        let result = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(appElement, kAXWindowsAttribute as CFString, &value)
        
        guard result == .success, let windows = value as? [AXUIElement], !windows.isEmpty else {
            if result == .success {
                print("No windows found for the application.")
            } else {
                print("Failed to retrieve windows, error: \(result)")
            }
            return
        }
        
        
        debugPrint(appElement)
        
    }
}

Whenever I do press my button combination, I get the output:
Failed to retrieve windows, error: AXError(rawValue: -25204)

I have accessibility permission enabled. Please let me know what I need to try next?
I'm on MacOS 14, using swift 5.
I added accessibility permission for my Mac app. I tried performing the button combinations on different open apps. I always get the same output.

[working code after sandbox fix]
import Cocoa
import ApplicationServices

struct WindowManager {
    func handleWindowResizeOperation() {
        self.getFocusedApp()
    }
    
    private func getFocusedApp() {
        let options: NSDictionary = [kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt.takeRetainedValue() as NSString: true]
        let accessEnabled = AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions(options)
        
        guard accessEnabled else {
            print("Accessibility permissions are not enabled.")
            return
        }
        
        guard let app = NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication else {
            print("No frontmost application found.")
            return
        }
        
        let appElement = AXUIElementCreateApplication(app.processIdentifier)
        
        var value: CFTypeRef?
        let result = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(appElement, kAXWindowsAttribute as CFString, &value)
        
        guard result == .success, let windows = value as? [AXUIElement], !windows.isEmpty else {
            if result == .success {
                print("No windows found for the application.")
            } else {
                print("Failed to retrieve windows, error: \(result)")
            }
            
            print("HERE!!!!!")
            return
        }
        
        if let firstWindow = windows.first {
            var newSize = CGSize(width: 800, height: 600) // Desired size
            var sizeValue: AXValue?

            sizeValue = AXValueCreate(AXValueType.cgSize, &newSize)

            if let sizeValue = sizeValue {
                let setSizeResult = AXUIElementSetAttributeValue(firstWindow, kAXSizeAttribute as CFString, sizeValue)
            
                if setSizeResult != .success {
                    print("Failed to resize window, error: \(setSizeResult)")
                }
            } else {
                print("Failed to create AXValue for size.")
            }
        }
        
        
        debugPrint(appElement)
        debugPrint("RESULT is \(result)")
        
    }
}

the full project if anyone is interested https://github.com/cosmicRover/goggles

Does this answer your question? AXUIElementCopyAttributeNames returns cannotComplete in Cocoa App but works well in playground
